# getting an error when configuring the backend state to use hdfs

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-flink

I am trying to set the backend state to hdfs

```
val stateUri = "hdfs/path_to_dir"
val backend: RocksDBStateBackend = new RocksDBStateBackend(stateUri, true)
env.setStateBackend(backend)
```

I am running with flink 1.7.0 with the following dependencies (I tried all combinations) :

```
   "org.apache.flink"    %% "flink-connector-filesystem"         % flinkV
"org.apache.flink"    % "flink-hadoop-fs"                     % flinkV
"org.apache.hadoop"   % "hadoop-hdfs"                         % hadoopVersion
"org.apache.hadoop"   % "hadoop-common"                       % hadoopVersion
```

however when running the jar I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 'hdfs'. The scheme is not directly supported by Flink and no Hadoop file system to support this scheme could be loaded.
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:403)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:318)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:298)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStorage.<init>(FsCheckpointStorage.java:58)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend.createCheckpointStorage(FsStateBackend.java:444)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateBackend.createCheckpointStorage(RocksDBStateBackend.java:407)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.<init>(CheckpointCoordinator.java:249)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Hadoop is not in the classpath/dependencies.
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedSchemeFactory.create(UnsupportedSchemeFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:399)
    ... 23 more
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you need a core-site.xml file on the classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing an `hdfs://` path it is not strictly necessary to bundle the `flink-hadoop-fs` with your job as long as you have `flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the `lib` folder of your Flink installation.

If you don't have this dependency in your `lib` folder, then I would suggest to use `flink-fs-hadoop-shaded` as a dependency because it also relocates Hadoop dependencies.

Moreover, it is important that this dependency is also included in your resulting job jar. Thus, please make sure that you create an uber-jar with `sbt-assembly` plugin.

Comment: Can you please explain how my dependency should look ? I tried to add that dependency but I am getting 
 `unresolved dependency: org.apache.flink#flink-fs-hadoop-shaded_2.11;1.7.0: not found`
getting the same for `flink-fs-hadoop-shade;1.7.0`

Comment: How do you submit Flink jobs and how do you deploy the Flink cluster?